# How to debug routes that require accept headers?

Tags: api, symfony, versioning, fosrestbundle

I'm following the FOSRest [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/versioning.html) on API versioning.

However it's not clear to me how the headers connect it to a specific controller using `media_type`.

Right now I'm sending the headers: `Accept: application/json;version=1.0` with Chrome extension *Postman* to `/api/user/status`

However I'm getting a `No route found for "POST /api/user/status"` error

Here's my configuration:

**routing.yml:**

```
type: rest
prefix: /api
resource: Acme\Bundle\SomeBundle\Controller\DefaultController
```

**DefaultController.php:**

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Version;

/**
 * @Version("1.0")
 * @RouteResource("User", pluralize=false)
*/
class User

...

public function postStatusAction()
```

**config.yml**

```
fos_rest:
    versioning:
        enabled: true
        resolvers:
            query: false
            custom_header: false
            media_type: 
                enabled: true
                regex: '/(v|version)=(?P<version>[0-9\.]+)/'
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
    view:
        mime_types:
            json: ['application/json;version=1.0']
    format_listener:
        enabled: true
```

**console debug:router post_user_status**

```
| Route Name   | post_user_status                                        |
| Path         | /api/user/status.{_format}                              |
| Path Regex   | #^/api/user/status(?:\.(?P<_format>json|xml|html))?$#s  |
| Host         | ANY                                                     |
| Host Regex   |                                                         |
| Scheme       | ANY                                                     |
| Method       | POST                                                    |
| Requirements | _format: json|xml|html                                  |
| Class        | Symfony\Component\Routing\Route                         |
| Defaults     | _controller: AcmeSomeBundle:Default:postStatus         |
|              | _format: json                                           |
| Options      | compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

I've also tried to no avail in **routing.yml** `condition: "request.attributes.get('version') == '1.0'"`

What am I missing?

Comment: Your mistake is in routing you must change `prefix: api` to `prefix: /api`

Comment: @MohammadZareMoghadam Thanks but even with that change I'm still getting the same error

Comment: add this to `format_listener` section:
`- { path: '^/api', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }`

Comment: @MohammadZareMoghadam That works; however it works only as a fallback not really because the underlying problem is fixed.

Comment: Also, I got it to work with `custom_header: true` and a `X-Accept-Version` header but I want to know why `media_type` doesn't work

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/format_listener.html

Comment: When you use `media-type` you must enable format listener

Comment: Thanks. Although even if I enable that if I change the controller to `@Version("1.2")` sending the header `Accept: application/json;version=1.2` still gives me the same error.

Comment: Because you must add `'application/json;version=1.2'` to mime types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks in part to @Mohammad in the comments for pointing me in the right direction I eventually found the answer.

While looking over the [FOSRest versioning documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/versioning.html) again the instructions are to be taken quite literally.

One of the requirements states

> You must configure the possible mime types for all supported versions:

Which means that since I only had:

```
view:
    mime_types:
        json: ['application/json;version=1.0']
```

Even if the in the header sent requested an API version that didn't exist it kept defaulting to this no matter what.

The correct config is

```
view:
    mime_types:
        json: ['application/json','application/json;version=1.0']
```

along with Mohhamad's mention that `media_type` headers require `format_listener`

```
format_listener:
    enabled: true
    rules:
        - { path: '^/api', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
```

With this it routes correctly to the right API version number.

It also finally routes to a 404 response if the version number is incorrect or if there is no API version header.